# How do i use the assets pipeline for generator-angular-fullstack for images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, gulp, angular-fullstack

**Context**:
I'm using the yo generator for `generator-angular-fullstack`

I've scaffolded my project using the gulp flag

I have gulp / express / angular running in development mode correctly

When i test gulp serve:dist i see the build process complete successfully

The build process seems to be implementing some type of asset caching logic for my images. When it optimizes the png images, it appends a suffix to the image name taking `foo.png` and changing it to `foo-4324hju2.png`. It does this for all assets in my project.

Resuling in:

```
foo-4324hju2.png
bar-5435fsgf.png
etc
```

**Problem**: When the browser loads the html file, its attempting to load assets from - /assets/images/foo.png - /assets/images/bar.png - This results in a 404 error.

**Question**: What is the correct way to integrate with the asset pipeline for  generator-angular-fullstack ?

Comment: seems pretty similar to https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1534 which has a short term fix in it

Comment: I'm not seeing a ref to 'filerev' anywhere in gulp on the most recent version